# SQL: Replace IN clause with JOIN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query, and I want to replace the IN clause with a JOIN clause to improve performance. However, I don't know how to do it when the IN clause is preceded by a START WITH clause. How would I fix this?

```
SELECT * FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 
    ON t2.var1 = t1.var1
    WHERE var2 = 0 START WITH var3 IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT var4 FROM t3) 
    CONNECT BY var3 = PRIOR t2.var5
```

I want it to look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
    INNER JOIN t2
    ON t2.var1 = t1.var1 
    WHERE var2 = 0 START WITH 
        (SELECT var3 FROM t3
        INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT var3 FROM t1)
        ON var3 = var4)
    CONNECT BY var3 = PRIOR t2.var5
```

The error I get when I run the second query is

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 1
```

I'm guessing it's because you have to follow `START WITH` with something besides a `SELECT`, but I don't know what to follow it with. The rest of the query is correct (don't worry about the `SELECT` statement in parentheses, it works).

Comment: please tag the dbms you are using

Comment: `connect by`? and `ORA-00933` lead me to believe it has to be Oracle right?

Comment: Yes, it's Oracle

Comment: Including table structures, sample data and current/expected results might be useful. The version of Oracle you're using might be helpful too; it may be easier/better to switch to a recursive CTE for instance, but that's only available from 11gR2 onwards.

Comment: You will get better results if you'll create an index on `t1( var3 )` column. I doubt if the join can help, it may even make thing worse. If you have performance problems, please generate an explain plan (run `EXPALIN PLAN FOR your_query` then `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XLAN.Display)`) and append it to the qustion.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't need to do much more than maybe replace your `IN` with an `EXISTS`.  Oracle does very advanced query optimization when you submit a query, and will convert `IN` and `EXISTS` to joins automatically at runtime.

In your case:

```
create table t1 ( var1 number );
create table t2 ( var1 number, var2 number, var3 number, var5 number );
create table t3 ( var4 number );

insert into t1 values  ( 1 );
insert into t1 values  ( 2 );
insert into t1 values  ( 3 );

insert into t3 values ( 99 );
insert into t3 values ( 99 );  -- Duplicates in T3!
insert into t3 values ( 99 );  -- Duplicates in T3!

insert into t2 values ( 1, 0, 99, 5 );
insert into t2 values ( 1, 0, 5, 6 );
insert into t2 values ( 1, 1, 6, 7 );
insert into t2 values ( 1, 0, 7, 8 );

insert into t2 values ( 2, 0, 99, 1 );
insert into t2 values ( 2, 0, 1, 2 );
insert into t2 values ( 2, 1, 1, 3 );
insert into t2 values ( 2, 0, 3, 4 );

SELECT *
FROM   t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.var1 = t1.var1
WHERE  var2 = 0
START WITH EXISTS ( SELECT 'x' FROM t3 WHERE var4 = var3 )
CONNECT BY var3 = PRIOR t2.var5 ;
```

#### Plan

You can see it joins everything and then does the `CONNECT BY` on the result.

```
7 SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS
    6 FILTER  
    Filter: "T2"."VAR2"=0  
        5 CONNECT BY NO FILTERING WITH START-WITH  
        Access: "T2"."VAR3"=PRIOR "T2"."VAR5"  
        Filter: EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "T3" "T3" WHERE "VAR4"=:B1)  
            3 HASH JOIN  
            Access: "T2"."VAR1"="T1"."VAR1"  
                1 TABLE ACCESS FULL APPS.T1 
                2 TABLE ACCESS FULL APPS.T2 
            4 TABLE ACCESS FULL APPS.T3 
            Filter: "VAR4"=:B1
```